# Can we have same cert with different alias in Java trustore?

Tags: java, truststore

Isit OK to have a same certificate with different alias within java truststore?
issuer of the certificate and serial no. also same.

ex:

Alias name: cert1
Owner: CN=xxxxxxx
Issuer: CN=yyyyyy

Alias name: cert2
Owner: CN=xxxxxxx
Issuer: CN=yyyyyy

Just wanted to know if this is OK.

Comment: Seems like you could have tested importing a cert with 2 different aliases almost as fast as typing out the question, no?